# No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp() but it already worked before, Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have the following problem with my Flutter Web Application:

When I try to to `flutter run` the Chrome Browser opens but I get the following Red Error Screen with this Message in the Terminal. The weird thing is, that it worked before. I updated the Flutter SDK to 3.7.0 and after that it didn't work anymore.

**Image**
[image]

**Terminal Output**

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following FirebaseException was thrown building Project(dirty):
[core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  Project
  Project:file:///Users/user/Desktop/dev/projectname/lib/main.dart:30:16

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 294:49  throw_
packages/firebase_core_web/src/firebase_core_web.dart 329:9                   app
packages/firebase_core/src/firebase.dart 56:41                                app
packages/firebase_auth/src/firebase_auth.dart 44:47                           get instance
packages/dashboardtest/main.dart 62:41                                        build
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5367:22                           build
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5297:15                           performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5016:7                            rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5279:5                            [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5273:5                            mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4182:15                           inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3707:18                           updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5322:16                           performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5016:7                            rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5279:5                            [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5273:5                            mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4182:15                           inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3707:18                           updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5322:16                           performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5462:11                           performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5016:7                            rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5279:5                            [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5453:11                           [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5273:5                            mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4182:15                           inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3707:18                           updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5322:16                           performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5016:7                            rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5279:5                            [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5273:5                            mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4182:15                           inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3707:18                           updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5322:16                           performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5016:7                            rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5279:5                            [_firstBuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5273:5                            mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4182:15                           inflateWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3707:18                           updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart 1253:16                             [_rebuild]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart 1222:5                              mount
packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart 1169:16                             <fn>
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 2719:19                           buildScope
packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart 1168:12                             attachToRenderTree
packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart 1000:24                             attachRootWidget
packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart 981:7                               <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/isolate_helper.dart 48:19       internalCallback

════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

**Part of my main.dart**

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  const FirebaseOptions firebaseOptions = FirebaseOptions(
    apiKey: "API_KEY",
    projectId: "projectId",
    messagingSenderId: "messagingSenderId",
    appId: "appId",
  );
  await Firebase.initializeApp(name: "name", options: firebaseOptions);

  runApp(const ParkbestDashboard());
}
```

**pubspec.yaml dependencies**

```
dependencies:
  blur: ^3.1.0
  cloud_firestore: ^4.4.5
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  email_validator: ^2.1.17
  firebase_auth: ^4.4.0
  firebase_auth_web: ^5.3.0
  firebase_core: ^2.15.1
  fl_chart: ^0.61.0
  fl_heatmap: ^0.2.0
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_heatmap_calendar: ^1.0.5
  flutter_styled_toast: ^2.1.3
  fluttertoast: ^8.2.1
  google_fonts: ^4.0.3
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.2.5
  google_maps_flutter_web: ^0.4.0+7
  intl: ^0.18.1
  pie_chart: ^5.3.2
  pointer_interceptor: ^0.9.3+4
  provider: ^6.0.5
  url_launcher: ^6.1.10

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

**flutter doctor -v Output**

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.3, on macOS 13.0.1 22A400 darwin-x64, locale de-DE)
    • Flutter version 3.13.3 on channel stable at /Users/user/Desktop/dev/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 2524052335 (6 days ago), 2023-09-06 14:32:31 -0700
    • Engine revision b8d35810e9
    • Dart version 3.1.1
    • DevTools version 2.25.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.1
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14C18
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.81.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.72.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • Jonas iPhone (2) (mobile) • 00008020-000205890163002E • ios            • iOS 16.3.1 20D67
    • macOS (desktop)           • macos                     • darwin-x64     • macOS 13.0.1 22A400 darwin-x64
    • Chrome (web)              • chrome                    • web-javascript • Google Chrome 116.0.5845.179
    ! Error: Jonas iPhone (2) is busy: Fetching debug symbols for Jonas iPhone (2). Xcode will continue when Jonas iPhone (2) is finished. (code -10)

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!
```

I hope someone had the same experience and my have a solution.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem! For me it was an old Version of the Imports inside the script tag of the /web/index.html:

I changed the version from `9.18.0` to `10.3.1`

Now it looks like this:

```
    import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.3.1/firebase-app.js";
    import { getAuth } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.3.1/firebase-auth.js";
    import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.3.1/firebase-analytics.js";
```